# up and down button should work only if either one item is selected or in case of multiple items only if consequtive items are selected

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

This code is used to move the item up and down the list using the two buttons. However in case of multiple select i need to move the items up and down the list only if the two or more items that are selected are consecutive. It should treat all the elements selected as single entity and should not change their order. I am I am not able to figure out how to do that. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>MS Profile</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script >
$(function()
{              
$("#buttonMoveUp").click(function() 
{
    $("select[id='selectObjChosen'] option:selected").each(function () 
    {
         itemlist=$('#selectObjChosen');
         selected=$(this).index();
         if(selected>2)
            {
                jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected-1)).before(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
                selected=selected-1;
            }
    });
 });

$("#buttonMoveDown").click(function() 
{
    $("select[id='selectObjChosen'] option:selected").each(function () 
    {
         itemlist=$('#selectObjChosen');
         selected=$(this).index();
         len=$(itemlist).children().length;
         if(selected < len && selected>=2)
             {
jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected+1)).after(jQuery($(itemlist).children().eq(selected)));
                selected=selected+1;
             }
    });
 });

});
</script>

<body>
<div >
<select id='selectObjChosen'  theme="simple" name="List"  multiple="multiple" class="right_select" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #01a9db; border-radius: 10px; height: 149px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; max-height: 270px; overflow-x: auto !important; overflow-y: hidden; padding: 7px; width: 100%;" >
<option value='ABC'>ABC</option>  
<option value='DEF'>DEF</option> 
<option value='PQR'>PQR</option>  
<option value='XYZ'>XYZ</option> 
<option value='MNO'>MNO</option>  
<option value='STU'>STU</option>    
</select> 
</div>                                  
<div style="width:45%; float:left; height:100px; padding-top: 70px;">
<input  type="button" name="^"  value="^" id="buttonMoveUp"/><br/><br/>
<input  type="button" name="v"  value="v" id="buttonMoveDown"/><br/>
</div>      
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: what should it do if they are not consecutive?

Comment: it should do nothing.. that is if non consecutive items are selected the buttons should get disabled.

Comment: i can be done in this way according to me: on $('#selectObjChosen').change if prevSelected-selected is not equal to mod(1) then the disabled property of the button should be set to true (disabled="disabled"). But i am not able to implement this logic.

Comment: implement which logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/7nsqh2bj/1/)

I rewrote your logic and came up with this.

**CODE**

```
$(function () {
    $("#buttonMoveUp").click(function () {
        var selectedItems = $("select[id='selectObjChosen'] option:selected");
        selectedItems.insertBefore(selectedItems.first().prev());
    });

    $("#buttonMoveDown").click(function () {
        var selectedItems = $("select[id='selectObjChosen'] option:selected");
        selectedItems.insertAfter(selectedItems.last().next());
    });

    $('#selectObjChosen').change(function () {
        var selectedItems = $("select[id='selectObjChosen'] option:selected");
        var error = 0;
        if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
            var prevElem = undefined;
            selectedItems.each(function (index, value) {
                if (typeof prevElem != "undefined") {
                    if (typeof $(prevElem).next()[0] != "undefined") {
                        if ($(prevElem).next()[0] != value) {
                            error = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                prevElem = value;
            })
        }
        if (error) {
            $('#buttonMoveUp,#buttonMoveDown').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#buttonMoveUp,#buttonMoveDown').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    })
});
```